# angularjs modal directly show content?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am newbie with angularjs

I want to use modal with bootstrap

but there is no any effect on my page

and there is no error message

here is my code

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
<div modal="shouldBeOpen" close="close()" options="opts">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-warning cancel" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
'use strict';

angular.module('yeomanContactsAppApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.open = function () {
      $scope.shouldBeOpen = true;
    };

$scope.close = function () {
  $scope.closeMsg = 'I was closed at: ' + new Date();
  $scope.shouldBeOpen = false;
};

$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2'];

$scope.opts = {
  backdropFade: true,
  dialogFade:true
};});
```

it result in directly show modal content , not click button to show modal ?
I am so confused , please help

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which bootstrap version are you using? If the html is the full bootstrap it looks like you are missing some parts like role='dialog' etc.

default set `$scope.shouldBeOpen` to false and then toggle it in your functions. Then it shouldn't open directly I think.

```
angular.module('yeomanContactsAppApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.shouldBeOpen = false;
...
});
```

The script works fine maybe its the html that is wrong. I used angular with bootstrap without any trouble.